# How to access Computed Properties like Role:img using selenium in Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, accessibility

[image: The Developer Tools Accessibility panel in dark mode is showing an Accessibility Tree with the selected node out of view, an empty grouping of ARIA Attributes, and then Computed Properties]

There are a set of properties retrieved under the Accessibility section of the webpage for the inspected element:

```
Computed Properties

Name: ""
`aria-labelledby`: Not specified
`aria-label`: Not specified
`title`: Not specified
Role: generic
```

These properties are returned under the computed Property category and are not visible inside the DOM.

To understand it better, it is more like what a browser interprets that element to be based on its definition.

```
Tried out the following methods unsuccessfully:

WebElement.getAttribute("Role")
WebElement.getCssValue("Role")
WebElement.findElement(By.cssSelector(".computed-property")
```

Comment: I tried to provide some background in my answer. To really help you, could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

How about [`getAriaRole()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAriaRole())

> `default java.lang.String getAriaRole()`
> Gets result of computing the WAI-ARIA role of element.

The role is computed as follows:

1. The role is taken from the `role` attribute, if present
2. If not, the element has the [implicit role assigned in the ARIA in HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#implicit)

---

Here is why what you tried doesn’t work.

```
WebElement.getAttribute("Role")
```

This only works for elements that have their role explicitly assigned via the `role` attribute, like `<div role="img">`. It does not work for the implicit role that `<img>` has.

```
WebElement.getCssValue("Role")
```

This would access the element’s `style` properties. There is no accessibility information in CSS, especially [no role property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#index).

```
WebElement.findElement(By.cssSelector(".computed-property")
```

This will search any element with `computed-property` in the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), set via the `class` attribute, “in the current context”.

I’m assuming you are trying to search for Chrome developer tools Accessibility panel with this? That’s not possible at all. It’s part of the the Chrome browser’s UI, and not part of the web page.